# How do I enable PHP 7.3 in Apache2

Tags: apache2, php7

I followed the instructions in https://idroot.us/install-php-7-3-ubuntu-18-04/ to install PHP 7.3 and then, as instructed, ran

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif

a2enconf php7.3-fpm
```

to enable it in Apache2.

```
systemctl status php7.3-fpm
```

confirms that php7.3 is installed and running and I did restart Apache2 using

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

`php -v` reports **PHP 7.3.6-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 31 2019 11:06:48) ( NTS )**

However, `phpinfo();` reports PHP 7.2: **PHP Version 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1**

What have I missed? Any guidance would be appreciated as I'm totally new to Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You have to disable the older version of PHP (a2dismod [oldversion]) and then enable the new version with

```
sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

Then restart apache2

Comment: `a2dismod php7.2` got rid of 7.2 and 7.3 appeared but 'a2enmod php7.3' failed, saying `ERROR: Module php7.3 does not exist!`.  
While that means I have a working 7.3 it looks like I have still messed up somewhere.  
How do I totally remove 7.2 (once I am happy 7.3 is fine)?

Comment: That means you haven't installed libapache2-mod-php7.3 yet.

Comment: Be aware that you've got to get 7.3 working in apache, AND mysql (probably 5.7.27 as of this post) working in php 7.3 - so the `php7.3-mysql` package is very important.  When you do `phpinfo()` from the browser, make sure it's showing mysql support as well.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had to do the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get install php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-mysql php7.3-gd php7.3-imagick php7.3-recode php7.3-tidy php7.3-xmlrpc php7.3-common php7.3-curl php7.3-mbstring php7.3-xml php7.3-bcmath php7.3-bz2 php7.3-intl php7.3-json php7.3-readline php7.3-zip

sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3

sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

After install apache still used php7.0, so I had to remove 7.0 configs manually:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
ls -la | grep php
sudo rm php7.0.conf
```

And finally

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Terrible idea, don't add a ppa for php. Also don't rm the conf files, the command is a2dismod.

Comment: @Nobody Why is it a terrible idea to add a PPA for PHP?

Comment: @slhck Because PPAs lower stability and security and in this case for no benefit at all.

Comment: @Nobody The benefit is that you get PHP 7.3 instead of 7.2. The PPA seems to be used a lot, so if anything you have more eyes on it.